# running an interactive plot on RStudio Presenter

Tags: r, plotly

My Plotly interactive plot written in R Markdown works fine with knitR.  When I try running it in R Studio's Presenter an error message appears on the slide:
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'webshot'

Previous R Markdown codes run fine in the Presenter, but not the plot.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install 'webshot' package which is causing this error.you can install it by simply typing following command in the console.

install.packages('webshot').